# How to remove or change the label of input field in CakePHP?

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have created a form by using the below code.

```html
<?php $this->Form->create('Course'); ?>
```

Form text element is displaying with label by the following...

```html
<?php $this->Form->input('code'); ?>
```

But i don't want to show the label of the text field.
what changes should be made in the above coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to change the label, use this.

```
$this->Form->input('code', array('label' => 'LabelName'));
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to remove the label you need to use:

```
   <?php echo $this->Form->input('code', array('label' => false)); ?>
```

For a full control of the label of an input, the best way is to use it like this:

```
   <?php echo $this->Form->input('code',array('label'=>array('text'=>'This is my label','class'=>' this is the class of my label'))); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->Form->input('code', array('label' => false));`

Or, if you wanted to change the label to something else of your choosing:

`$this->Form->input('code', array('label' => 'something else'));`